# NSURL URLWithString gives error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my new app I have to external links. One in the view that only is shown the very first time the app is started and one in tab3. The link in tab3 is working, but the link in the initial screen is giving a crash, while exactly the same code is used.

Code for ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)findAllyId;
```

Code for ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)findAllyId {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtu.be/H_AguOLEHW8"]];
}
```

Error log after pressing the Button that is linked to this findAllyId

```
2015-03-13 19:03:30.666 Friend codes for Kingdom Age[89581:40810062] -[ViewController findAllyId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facaa694530
2015-03-13 19:03:30.674 Friend codes for Kingdom Age[89581:40810062] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController findAllyId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facaa694530'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e141a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dddabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e148d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0a09dc ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e0a0578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010c430a22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
6   UIKit                               0x000000010c537e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
7   UIKit                               0x000000010c53721f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
8   UIKit                               0x000000010c476b68 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
9   UIKit                               0x000000010c477493 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
10  UIKit                               0x000000010c443fb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
11  UIKit                               0x000000010c451227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
12  UIKit                               0x000000010c42c23c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e076c91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e06cb5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e06c194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e06bbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fc5aa58 GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x000000010c42f580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
19  Friend codes for Kingdom Age        0x000000010b9f9d83 main + 115
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e6af145 start + 1
21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Again, exactly the same code (with a different URL) is working in another screen of the app, with a click on a button.

Comment: I think the crash is not in openurlcode method. You have not correctly defind the IBAction method. Add -(IBAction) findAllyId:(id) sender'

Comment: Changed it to your suggestion. Unfortunately with the same crash. In my tab3 I do have the same (IBAction) and there the link opens Safari and shows the website.

Comment: The button might be probably connected to some other action. Remove ibaction from story board and connect it again.

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was that there was two times an @end in the .h and .m in of the ViewController. I added the code for the IBAction before the first '@end' and the URL code before the second '@end'